# Troubles using Which or Piecewise to define a function

Tags: piecewise

I have a very simple task, but for some reason I fail to accomplish it. I want to use `Which` to define a function. I think the code is self-explanatory:

```
In: f[x_, y_] := Which[x == en, 1, y == en, 2]

In: f[en, a]
Out: 1
```

OK, so far so good. But if other condition is satisfied, nothing happens:

```
In: f[a, en]
Out: Which[a == en, 1, en == en, 2]
```

I would expect to get `2` as output, not this. Why is this so?

I got same result if I use numbers instead of the symbolic expressions, and same result if I use `Piecewise` instead of `Which`.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your case you should use `===` ([`SameQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SameQ.html)) instead of `==` ([`Equal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Equal.html)) in your definition.

The problem you are facing is caused by the fact that `Equal` (`==`) does *not* evaluate to True / False unless it has values to compare (see an illustrative example in the ["Basic Examples" section](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SameQ.html#23816) of the documentation for `SameQ`).

```
f[x_, y_] := Which[x === en, 1, y === en, 2]

f[en, a] (* Out: 1 *)
f[a, en] (* Out: 2 *)
```

The same applies in the case of a `Piecewise` definition:

```
fp[x_, y_] := Piecewise[{{1, x === en}, {2, y === en}}]
fp[en, a] (* Out: 1 *)
fp[a, en] (* Out: 2 *)
```